# Make calc on dates using informix db

Tags: sql, date, informix

I want to put the following condition in my query ,but i don't know the correct syntax in informix to do that .

> At least one year passed on his work date ..

So

---

I try some thing like that

```
b.work_date - CURRENT >= 12   -- 12 month
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
b.work_date <= CURRENT - 12 UNITS MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the `CURRENT - 12 UNITS MONTH` approach. It does not take the leap-day in February into account, and would explode with an `Invalid day in date` error if you ran it on 2012-04-29.

It is safer to write

```
b.work_date < TODAY - 365
```